# LinkedIdentityHashSet

Tags: java, collections

I know both the [`IdentityHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) (via [`Collections#newSetFromMap(Map)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29))and the [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). However, what I need is a combination of the two, a `LinkedIdentityHashSet`. I could not find any ready-made solution on the net. Anybody knows how to tweak this?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation techniques there don't marry up very well. `LinkedHashMap` adds linked listing to the entry objects of the map. `IdentityHashMap` uses a probing technique and so avoids having any entry objects.

There's a few ways to add "identity" characteristics to a collection/map.

- Force the key type to behave correctly with `final` `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Really all reference-type types should have this, but never mind.
- If you can't modify `equals` and `hashCode` but can modify the class, add a `final` field that is of a `final` class that holds a `final` references to the type you were going to use as the key. Use the new field as the key.
- Store adaptor objects in the collection/map. You will need to create a new adaptor instance for each lookup. It just has its `equals`/`hashCode` methods to call `==`/`System.identityHashCode` on the original object.

Comment: sometimes you just need IdentityHashMap, these are the cases where you have *both* a normal HashMap with some custom equality relation, but still need the identity equality relation in another context (i had this situation once)

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use LinkedHashSet and a wrapper

```
class LinkedIdentityHashSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {
    Set set = new LinkedHashSet();

    static class IdentityWrapper {
        Object obj;

        IdentityWrapper(Object obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return this.obj == obj;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return System.identityHashCode(obj);
        }
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        return set.add(new IdentityWrapper(e));
    }
...
```

Comment: The equals method should be comparing `this.obj` to `((IdentityWrapper) obj).obj`.

Comment: Since that line is simply checking reference equality, the cast is not necessary. The references will be the same (or different) at runtime, regardless of what type they are at compile time.

Comment: I like the idea conceptually. Downvoted because of a bug mentioned by @MikeSamuel.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom Map that uses Wrapper objects that use the identity semantics, and use a LinkedHashSet internally that uses these Wrapper Objects.