# Implementing an IdentityLinkedHashSet by Wrapping a LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, hashset

In the Java standard library, a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) is the same as [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) but with predictable iteration order (insertion-order). I need an `IdentityHashSet` (which uses object-identity or reference-equality, instead of object-equality) with predictable iteration order (insertion-order).

While there is no `IdentityHashSet` in Java's standard library, you can easily create one using the available [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) with the following statement:

```java
Set<T> identitySet = java.util.Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<>());
```

This is almost the same implementation used in Guava's [`Sets.newIdentityHashSet()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newIdentityHashSet--); but this has the unspecified, generally chaotic ordering of [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) keys (and [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) elements).

My searches for an implementation of an `IdentityLinkedHashSet` had no results, so I decided to implement it myself. One useful result which I found was [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277397/1609705), which suggests to use an identity-wrapper class in composition with [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

I tried to implement this idea. Below is some key snippet of my implementation. [**Access the full Gist here**](https://gist.github.com/ghaffarian/b487528bc69c3b08f79087c6db00dcec).

```java
public class IdentityLinkedHashSet<E> implements Set<E> {

    private LinkedHashSet<IdentityWrapper> set;

    /* ... constructors ... */

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return set.add(new IdentityWrapper(e));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object obj) {
        return set.contains(new IdentityWrapper((E) obj));
    }

    /* ... rest of Set methods ... */

    private class IdentityWrapper {

        public final E ELEM;

        IdentityWrapper(E elem) {
            this.ELEM = elem;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return obj != null && ELEM == obj;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return System.identityHashCode(ELEM);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a few unit-tests to verify my implementation. Unfortunately some of the assertions fail! Here are my tests:

```java
String str1 = new String("test-1");
String str2 = new String("test-2");
String str3 = new String("test-2");

Set<String> identitySet = new IdentityLinkedHashSet<>();

assertTrue(idSet.add(str1));
assertFalse(idSet.add(str1));       //  <-- fails!
assertTrue(idSet.contains(str1));   //  <-- fails!
//
assertTrue(idSet.add(str2));
assertFalse(idSet.add(str2));       //  <-- fails!
assertTrue(idSet.contains(str2));   //  <-- fails!
assertFalse(idSet.contains(str3));
//
assertTrue(idSet.add(str3));
assertFalse(idSet.add(str3));       //  <-- fails!
assertTrue(idSet.contains(str3));   //  <-- fails!
assertEquals(3, idSet.size());      //  <-- fails!
```

**What have I done wrong in this implementation?**

Comment: Side note: `IdentityWrapper` doesn't need to know the element type so instead of using `E` I'd just use `Object` to avoid confusion as well as that `(E) obj` cast which will generate a warning.

Comment: You should further note that `equals()` will get passed another `IdentityWrapper` by the inner set. That's why your test fails - the object and the wrapper are not the same instance. You'd need to cast to `IdentityWrapper` and compare its `ELEM` instead (step through your code with a debugger to see for yourself).

Comment: @Thomas As you and Lino mentioned, that was exactly the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the `IdentityWrapper.equals()` method. The `LinkedHashSet` will not pass the `ELEM` but rather an `IdentityWrapper` object.

You have to introduce an additional check (`instanceOf`) and then unwrap the passed object to compare the elements:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof IdentityLinkedHashSet<?>.IdentityWrapper) && 
        ELEM == ((IdentityLinkedHashSet<?>.IdentityWrapper) obj).ELEM;
}
```

Some notes:

1. `instanceof` will check for null, so you can remove that check entirely.
2. You have to reference `IdentityWrapper` like this: `IdentityLinkedHashSet<?>.IdentityWrapper` because it is not a `static` class. As noted in the comments. It can be made static, and the type of the `ELEM` can be changed from `E` to `Object`. Which would you leave also with a nicer `equals` method:

   ```
   private static class IdentityWrapper {

       public final Object ELEM;

       IdentityWrapper(Object elem) {
           this.ELEM = elem;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           return (obj instanceof IdentityWrapper) && ELEM == ((IdentityWrapper) obj).ELEM;
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           return System.identityHashCode(ELEM);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This tiny mistake was exactly the issue and now all the tests pass. One question: other than shorter referencing, is there any other benefit to making `IdentityWrapper` static?

Comment: @SeyedMohammad I figured out the answer: "if the inner-class has no need to access members of the outer class, it's preferred to be static." [Ref-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) + [Ref-2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16147405/1609705)